# NServiceBus return not working when using the gateway

Tags: nservicebus

I've been playing about trying to get the gateway working across sites for NServiceBus. I know you cannot do pub/sub across sites, but you are able to issue a reply. There is however no mention of return not working, has anyone managed to get this to work or is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not seen any issues for this raised, it appears that although messages were returned to the source service the register callback would never be fired. I've not dug much further into this since updating to a later version seems to have resolved this.